# Как присвоить переменной char значение слова

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, строковый-литерал

Нужно осуществить что-то типа этого

```
userName="DeadUser"
```

Это значение присваивается переменной отдельной функцией

Comment: Если она именно `char` (не `char []` и не `char *`), то никак. Только одну букву. По секрету -- иногда можно загнать в нее аж 4 (но особо  баловаться не стоит, пуристы заклюют)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от того, как объявлена переменная. Если она объявлена как указатель, то вы можете написать

```
char *userName = "DeadUser";
```

или

```
char *userName;
userName = "DeadUser";
```

или даже

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

char *userName;
userName = malloc( 9 * sizeof( char ) );
strcpy( userName, "DeadUser" );

//...

free( userName );
```

Если переменная объявлена как массив, то вы можете написать

```
char userName[] = "DeadUser";
```

или

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char userName[9];
strcpy( userName, "DeadUser" );
```

Comment: Такое "секретное оружие", как `strdup()` рано еще ему доверять?

Comment: @avp Вообще-то, это не стандартная функция. Это POSIX функция. Ей можно пользоваться, но чтобы код компилировался, нужно либо задать макрообъявление, либо опцию компилятора.

Comment: Ну, Вы даете. И с каких это пор POSIX не стандарт? Вообще, если в gnu есть, то можно пользоваться. А если где-то ее (или какой другой) и не будет, значит самому надо там реализовать.

Comment: @avp POSIX - не указ C стандарту.:)

Comment: **POSIX - не указ C стандарту.:)** О Господи... А вот это : "POSIX (англ. portable operating system interface — переносимый интерфейс операционных систем) — набор стандартов, описывающих интерфейсы между операционной системой и прикладной программой (системный API), библиотеку языка C и набор приложений и их интерфейсов. " - ничего не значит? Стандарт, в котором оговариваются БИБЛИОТЕКИ С не указ для БИБЛИОТЕК С ?!

Comment: Тогда прямо хочется сказать -- вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: @avp Да, ваша цитата ничего не значит. Иначе бы эту функцию включили бы в стандарт. Что касается "ехать", то с этим проблем нет. Кстати сказать, например, я лично очень плохо отношусь к тем программистам. которые в свой код включают средства boost, когда то же самое можно сделать стандартными средствами языка. Обычно это приводит к тому, что люди просто не умеют писать код и самостоятельно мыслить.

Comment: @MrShef Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)